# Why were Elizabethan English concerned about vagabonds?

Tags: united-kingdom, 16th-century

I have an assessment soon, and part of my revision is on poverty in Elizabethan England. This includes Explaining why Elizabethans were worried about Vagabonds. I am unsure on this topic, but I have researched some possible reasons:

- The Mass groups worried Elizabethans due to the peasants revolts becoming a possibility.
- They were worried about the spreading of disease.

However to answer the question I must provide a third reason and also back each point up with evidence. Furthermore, I am familiar with the reasons for Poverty, and the existing help that was there, and I also understand that the Vagabonds act of 1572 persecuted these 'rogues' but I am still unsure of why they persecuted beggars without a licence or vagabonds, and what it was that worried them, particularly the gentry and nobility in the Early years of Elizabeth's reign (1558-1588). I would be grateful for any help that can be offered.

Comment: Welcome to History! You need to start about by showing us what research you have done yourself.

Comment: Serfdom was on the decline, which meant that many people had to wander the country looking for work - or charity. Undoubtedly many of them turned to crime as well. Go to Wikipedia and read about the old poor law

Comment: Poor harvests, the loss of monastic charity, enclosure of common land for sheep rearing - some of the reasons for rising poverty. [This](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/z3nqsg8/revision/2) might be a starting point.

Comment: @NeMo - Would you consider fleshing that out into an answer?

Comment: Also, I know this is for an assignment, but you also need to show why you think Elizabethans were worried about vagabonds. If your textbook mentions this, you can cite it. Otherwise, that may be part of your research toward the question.

Comment: @Richard herman  Please explain the meaning of the phrase " revising for my mocks".

Comment: Mock exams=practice exams before the real thing

Comment: Note also that people could usually only claim for Church support in their _home_ parish (ie where they were born). people who chose to leave/had to leave could end up as vagabonds